# syntax error when using case / if/else inside mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am using a case statement in my MySQL trigger.
But getting a syntax error when using a case block / if/else inside a trigger in MySQL.

**USING CASE**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
       TRIGGER `color_changed` 
       AFTER INSERT ON `tb_tickets`
       FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
 CASE NEW.program_id
 WHEN 1 THEN
   UPDATE tb_sites_1 
   SET color_status = NEW.status 
   WHERE site_id = NEW.site_id;
 WHEN 2 THEN
   UPDATE tb_sites_2 
   SET color_status = NEW.status 
   WHERE site_id = NEW.site_id;
 WHEN 3 THEN
   UPDATE tb_sites_3
   SET color_status = NEW.status 
   WHERE site_id = NEW.site_id;
 END
END
DELIMITER ;
```

**error**
 Sorry an unexpected error happened!

**USING IF/ELSE**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
       TRIGGER `color_changed` 
       AFTER INSERT ON `tb_tickets`
       FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
 IF NEW.program_id = 1 THEN
   UPDATE tb_sites_1 
   SET color_status = NEW.status 
   WHERE site_id = NEW.site_id;
 ELSEIF NEW.program_id = 2 THEN
   UPDATE tb_sites_2 
   SET color_status = NEW.status 
   WHERE site_id = NEW.site_id;
 ELSE
  UPDATE tb_sites_3
   SET color_status = NEW.status 
   WHERE site_id = NEW.site_id;
 END
END;
```

**error**

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9**

Comment: What exactly does the syntax error state?

Comment: #1064 .You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10 @EricJ.

Comment: Are you setting delimiters?

Comment: the case statement needs to be terminated with end case; and and if statement need to be terminated with an end if; and the end that matchs the begin should be terminated with whatever you set the delimiter to.

Comment: Please read this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: used delimeter now getting sorry an unexpected error happened @P.Salmon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always best to read the whole comment. You missed the end case; and  end // (for the begin)

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER T
       AFTER INSERT ON `tb_tickets`
       FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
 CASE NEW.program_id
 WHEN 1 THEN
   UPDATE tb_sites_1 
   SET color_status = NEW.status 
   WHERE site_id = NEW.site_id;
 WHEN 2 THEN
   UPDATE tb_sites_2 
   SET color_status = NEW.status 
   WHERE site_id = NEW.site_id;
 WHEN 3 THEN
   UPDATE tb_sites_3
   SET color_status = NEW.status 
   WHERE site_id = NEW.site_id;
 END CASE;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

If you have any other errors please add the full error.

Comment: I am facing another trigger error could you please help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56964816/error-1054-unknown-column-program-id-in-new