# ERROR #1054 - Unknown column 'program_id' in 'NEW

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

**Tring to achieve-**

I am trying to update color_status in tb_sites_3 (3 will be dynamic based on program_id which we will get from tb_tickets) Whenever any insert is made on tb_jobs.

**ERROR**

While creating a trigger I am getting the following error 
**ERROR #1054 - Unknown column 'program_id' in 'NEW'**

**tb_tickets**
[image: tb_tickets]

**tb_jobs**

[image]

**tb_sites_3**

[image]

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER trig_job_color
           BEFORE INSERT ON `tb_jobs`
           FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
    SET NEW.program_id = (Select program_id from tb_tickets
    where tb_tickets.job_id = NEW.job_id);
    SET NEW.status = (Select status from tb_tickets
    where tb_tickets.job_id = NEW.job_id);

     CASE NEW.program_id
     WHEN 1 THEN
       UPDATE tb_sites_1 
       SET color_status = NEW.status 
       WHERE site_id = NEW.site_id;
     WHEN 2 THEN
       UPDATE tb_sites_2 
       SET color_status = NEW.status 
       WHERE site_id = NEW.site_id;
     WHEN 3 THEN
       UPDATE tb_sites_3
       SET color_status = NEW.status 
       WHERE site_id = NEW.site_id;
     END CASE;
    END //
    DELIMITER ;
```

**Table definations**

**tb_tickets**

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_tickets` (
 `id` int(15) NOT NULL,
 `ticket_id` int(15) NOT NULL,
 `job_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `site_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `program_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `status` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**tb_jobs**

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_jobs` (
 `job_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `job_creation` date DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`job_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**tb_sites_3**

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_sites_3` (
 `id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `color_status` int(15) NOT NULL,
 `site_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: The trigger is on tb_jobs so NEW. values only refer to that table.

Comment: but to get program_id I have to make a join on tb_jobs and tb_tickets as program_id, status is contained in tb_tickets @P.Salmon

Comment: Perhaps you should be using declared variables? Don't forget all I'm seeing is non working code, you haven't described what you are trying to achieve. You should also add table definitions, sample data, and insert statement and expected outcome as text.

Comment: I want to update color_status in tb_sites_3 if any insert is made in tb_jobs. @P.Salmon

Comment: And can you have multiple inserts into tb.jobs for job_id 1(for example) and what is a limit by without an order by (rhetorical question - pretty useless)

Comment: No job_id is a primary key @P.Salmon

Comment: added table_definations and what I am trying to achieve.@P.Salmon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196240/discussion-between-art-and-p-salmon).

Comment: as @P.Salmon said the trigger is on tb_jobs. You can not use NEW.program_id or NEW.status or NEW.site_id in your trigger.

Comment: then how can we achieve this @olegsv

Comment: Define the trigger on tb_tickets, not on tb_jobs.

Answer (score 1):

CREATE TRIGGER `trig_job_color` AFTER INSERT ON `tb_jobs`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET @program_id = (Select program_id from tb_tickets
    where tb_tickets.job_id = NEW.job_id);

```
SET @newstatus = (Select status from tb_tickets
where tb_tickets.job_id = NEW.job_id);
SET @newsite_id = (Select site_id from tb_tickets
where tb_tickets.job_id = NEW.job_id);

CASE @program_id
 WHEN 1 THEN
   UPDATE tb_sites_3 
   SET tb_sites_3.color_status = @newstatus 
   WHERE tb_sites_3.site_id = @newsite_id;
 WHEN 2 THEN
   UPDATE tb_sites_3 
   SET tb_sites_3.color_status = @newstatus 
   WHERE tb_sites_3.site_id = @newsite_id;
 WHEN 3 THEN
   UPDATE tb_sites_3
   SET tb_sites_3.color_status = @newstatus 
   WHERE tb_sites_3.site_id = @newsite_id;
 END CASE;
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using variables.

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER trig_job_color
           AFTER INSERT ON `tb_jobs`
           FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
    DECLARE x, y INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE z varchar(50);
    SET x = (Select program_id from tb_tickets
    where tb_tickets.job_id = NEW.job_id);
    SET y = (Select status from tb_tickets
    where tb_tickets.job_id = NEW.job_id);
    SET Z = (Select site_id from tb_tickets
    where tb_tickets.job_id = NEW.job_id);
     CASE x
     WHEN 1 THEN
       UPDATE tb_sites_1 
       SET color_status = y
       WHERE site_id = z;
     WHEN 2 THEN
       UPDATE tb_sites_2 
       SET color_status = y
       WHERE site_id = z;
     WHEN 3 THEN
       UPDATE tb_sites_3
       SET color_status = y 
       WHERE site_id = z;
     END CASE;
    END //
    DELIMITER ;
```